# How to set variable from child_process.exec()

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

I have a simple function to run a system app from the web.

```
server.route({
  method: 'POST',
  path: '/executeMain',
  handler: (req, res) => {
    var success = false;
    exec("./main", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log('error: ' + error.message);
        return;
      }
      if (stderr) {
        console.log('error: ' + stderr);
        return;
      }
      console.log(stdout);
      success = true;
    });

    if (success) {
      return res.response("OK").code(200);
    }
    else {
      return res.response("ERR").code(500);
    }
  }
});
```

In exec function, I want to set success to true, but it never happens. Can anybody help me and explain to me why this is don't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`child_process.exec()` is an asynchronous function. So the process starts running the background and the function returns immediately. So you are checking the value of `success` before the process finishes and before it's been set.

Your handler will need to also be asynchronous since it relies on the return value of an asynchronous function. Something like:

```js
server.route({
  method: 'POST',
  path: '/executeMain',
  handler: (req, res) => {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        exec("./main", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log('eror: ' + error.message);
                reject( res.response("ERR").code(500) )
            }
            if (stderr) {
                console.log('error: ' + stderr);
                reject( res.response("ERR").code(500) )
            }

            console.log(stdout);
            resolve( res.response("OK").code(200) )
        });
    });
}
```

On another note, you probably don't want to throw an error just because `stderr` is true. Many programs write to stderr even when successful.

Comment: You don't even need to return a promise and resolve or reject it.  The callback passed to exec can just write the result with `res.response(…).code(…)`  In fact, you've introduced the possibility for an unhandled promise rejection.